# Can i use an expression from ctrl in default input value in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Can i use an expression from controller $scope in default input value in angularjs?

i mean something like this.

```
<input name="somename" id="someid" type="hidden" ng-model="tempmodel" ng-init="tempmodel={{ datafromcontroller.field }}">
```

i need a hidden input field with some default data. In a plain html with php would be something like..

```
<input name="somename" id="someid" type="hidden" value="<?php $var ?>">
```

Thank u and sorry for my english xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and works!

```
<input name="somename" id="someid" type="hidden" ng-model=datafromcontroller.field>
```